# Why do we write "original 13 colonies" rather than "13 original colonies"?

Tags: word-order

Unfortunately, English is not my native language. So I decided to ask a question; I think it's always better to ask one than to remain an ignoramus for the rest of life.

Why do we say and write "original 13 colonies" rather than "13 original colonies"? It's a very popular Google research; for instance, here you can follow a link provided by Google: https://www.landofthebrave.info/american-history-of-13-colonies.htm

But we say "three wise monkeys" rather than "wise three monkeys", don't we?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we say "three wise monkeys". Imagine though if a fourth wise monkey joined the troop later on. We would describe the founding members as *the original three wise monkeys*.

In most contexts, it wouldn't really matter which way around you said it.

> A new fourth member has joined the original three wise monkeys.
>    **or**
>   A new fourth member has joined the three original wise monkeys.

**Unless**, of course, you considered "Three Wise Monkeys" a *collective noun*, like "*The Rolling Stones*" is the name of a band, in which case you wouldn't break it up by inserting "original" into the middle of it.

The "[Thirteen Colonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteen_Colonies)" appears to be a commonly used collective noun to describe the first British colonies of the USA. Therefore, like a band name, you wouldn't want to break it up, and that is why your document says "the original thirteen colonies" and not "thirteen original colonies". It seems like it is necessary to state that they are the "original", presumably to contrast them with the present 50 states of America that make up the USA.

Comment: I agree with this reasoning.  I would add that “13 original colonies” does not sound too bad.  But (considering the monkeys example) it might imply that *more* colonies could follow.  We know that more than 13 colonies were not created. So keeping “13 colonies” together (as a band name) makes sense.   It wasn’t “the original 13 out of 20 colonies.”